# How to reset `\setcolumnwidth` with paracol

Tags: paracol

I wound up answering my own question while working on the MWE, but the result was interesting.  Perhaps I should rename the question "Why does `\columnsep=0pt` give me an error when I reset paracol?"

Basically, I can easily switch between `\begin{paracol}{4}` and `\begin{paracol{3}` until I use `\setcolumnwidth` at which point I have to change it every time.  I tried using `\setcolumnwidth{}` and got an error.  But when I added it to my MWE, it worked!

It turns out that the error only occurs if you set `\columnsep=0pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{4}
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{3}
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}

\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-0.75\columnsep}% set globally
\begin{paracol}{2}
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\end{paracol}%
\setcolumnwidth{}% rset column widths

\begin{paracol}{3}
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}
should match second row

\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
\setcolumnwidth{0.25\textwidth}% set globally
\begin{paracol}{2}
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\end{paracol}%
\setcolumnwidth{}

Will get error here
\begin{paracol}{3}
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\switchcolumn
\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: In case you are wondering what sort of document I was working on. see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/chess/3801-3900.pdf (I only add 2 puzzles/day).

Comment: The package itself uses [`\columnratio{}\relax`](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paracol/paracol.sty?view=markup&pathrev=49560#l2123) to initialize the setting, hence I guess it is safer than `\setcolumnwidth{}`. Another guess is, the `1sp` in `\ifdim\@tempdima=\z@ \@tempdima1sp\relax\fi`, [`\pcol@setcw@calcf`](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paracol/paracol.sty?view=markup&pathrev=49560#l2217) is too small. `1pt` seems to work but is this too large? (1pt = 65,536sp).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ - Truth is, I was mostly using `\columnsep=0pt` just to so I could use `0.25\textwidth` instead of `\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-0.75\columnsep`.  Now I set `\columnsidth=1pt` and ignore the fact the `0.25\textwidth` is 0.75pt too wide.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a few colors helps clarify the problem.

Even setting `\columnnsep` to a very small value to avoid the overflow error in the calculations of the column and gap width (see the manual, section 7.3 for the details), the result is wrong: **the green line is missing**, as you can see from the last line.

The conflict is caused by setting `\setcolumnwidth{0pt}` to reset the width of the columns, which is not necessary.

Responding to the title of your question:

> The setting of column width by the command takes effect in the paracol
> environments following the command. Therefore, though placing the
> command in the preamble is the most natural way, you may place this
> command between two paracol environments to change the column layout
> for the second one, even when they appear in a page.

In conclusion, `\columnnsep = 0pt` does not throw any error.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    
{\Large New code}
    
\begin{paracol}{4}
    \color{green}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{blue}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{black}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{3}
    \color{green}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{blue}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}

\bigskip

\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-0.75\columnsep}% set globally
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \color{green}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}%

%   \setcolumnwidth{0pt}% rset column widths WRONG <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{paracol}{3}
    \color{green}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{red} \rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{blue}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}

\bigskip

Should match second row with no column separations (YES)

\setcolumnwidth{0.25\textwidth}% set globally
    
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt} % is OK <<<
    
\begin{paracol}{2}      
    \color{green}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}%

%   \setcolumnwidth{0pt} % reset column widths WRONG  <<<<<<<<<<<<<

With columnsep =0pt we will get error here (NO)
\begin{paracol}{3}
    \color{green}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn           
    \color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{blue}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}


\vspace*{50pt}

{\Large Former code}


Should match second row with no column separations

 (Does not happens: missing green rule)


\setcolumnwidth{0.25\textwidth}% set globally

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.02pt}  % OK <<<

\begin{paracol}{2}      
    \color{green}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}%

\setcolumnwidth{0pt} % rset column widths WRONG <<<<<

Will get error here (only if columnsep=0pt,

 but wrong result anyway, even if columnsep=0.02pt)
\begin{paracol}{3}
    \color{green}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn           
    \color{red}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
    \switchcolumn
    \color{blue}\rule{\columnwidth}{1ex}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setcolumnwidth{}` and `\setcolumnwidth{0pt}` are completely different in effect.